# Cannot install GTK+3 on Windows

Tags: gtk3, msys, msys2

I'm trying to install GTK+3 on Windows 10 64-bit version 1803, and I'm following instructions on [GTK+ Download: Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php), but I'm getting this error on Step 2:

```
MSYS ~
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

I've tried almost all solution on web, and none of them resolved the problem.

Comment: Remove and reinstall, maybe?

Comment: @theGtknerd no. I did complete remove and reinstall about 3-4 times, and that didn't help.

Comment: `pacman -Syyuu` help?

Comment: @LaraMaia that didn't help neither.

Comment: You're running it inside ConEmu or something like that?

Comment: @LaraMaia no. I'm running it directly in Windows through its cmd launcher.

Comment: It's possible thaat something in [this discussion](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/393) may help you.  That said, the MSYS devs [have stated](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/discussion/general/thread/86b16f3f/) that they do not support 64-bit Windows and do not intend to.